# Is the series $X =\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+..$ convergent or divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, twin-primes

The series is the reciprocal of twin primes. Let $Y=(y_n)$be the series of reciprocal of natural numbers.  Now if I use the comparison test we can see that each term of $0 <(x_n) < (y_n)$ .So the divergence of series of reciprocal of  natural number should also imply the same for $Y$. Now the problems of my proof:

$1)$ I probably have used the comparison test in a wrong sense

$2)$ I don't know how many twin primes are there

Can someone help me to understand the intuition behind the statement. If it converges or diverges why? I don't need the entire proof but some hint would do..

Comment: The series converges by Brun's Theorem and an application of the comparison test.

Comment: Can you suggest me where I can find the proof of it?

Comment: See for example [thisProof](http://math.uga.edu/~lyall/Analysis/brunsieve.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result and its proof have already been provided in the comments. To answer your question about the intuition behind it: Based on the [random model of the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture#Heuristic_justification), the [first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#Conjectures) estimates the density of twin primes (and similar prime constellations) at $x$ to be of the order of $\frac1{\ln^2x}$. Based on this estimate and the fact that the integral

$$
\int_a^\infty \frac1x\frac1{\ln^2x}\mathrm dx=\frac1{\ln a}
$$

converges, we should expect the sum of the reciprocals of the twin primes to converge.

Comment: I know this might sound a bit stupid but I went through the proof suggested by @almagest and I really wanted to know how does one derive the intuitions of such proofs? Nothing of this sort popped in my mind..how does one do it?

Comment: @GuriaSona: In my view, one develops intuitions for an area by working on problems in that area.