# Is the series $X=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+..$ divergent or convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, geometric-progressions

I am trying to use the comparision test over here $Y= 1+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+..$ . Show that $0<(x_n)<=(y_n)$ . Since $Y$ diverges we see that the $X$ also diverges.

$(1)$ am I using the comparision test correctly?

$(2)$is there any other crude way to prove this instead of using theorems

Comment: You are using the test incorrectly: just because a **bigger** series diverges, it does not mean that the **smaller** series diverges.

Comment: Should I try to show that a subsequence is not bounded?

Comment: You assumption to use comparision test is not right, it works it opposite senseyou used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is divergent, since by the comparison test
$$
1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots \geq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots
$$
which is $\tfrac12$ times the famous harmonic series
$$
1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots
$$
which is [known to diverge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test).

Answer (score 3):

If so, we obtain:
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...=$$
$$=1+(X-1)+\frac{1}{2}(X-1)+\frac{1}{2^2}(X-1)+\ldots=1+\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}(X-1)=2X-1,$$ which says that $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\ldots$$ converges, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

by term-by-term comparison the given sum is greater than $ \frac 1 4 \left(1+\frac  12+\frac 1 3+\ldots\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another approach. By Riemann sums, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{2k-1}\geq\int_1^n\frac1{2x-1}dx=\frac12\ln(2n-1),$$ so that the sum to infinity diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The series is strictly larger (at precisely each term) than the sum of the reciprocals of the primes which is known to diverge.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\gt \dfrac{1}{2n}= (1/2)\dfrac{1}{n}$.

The harmonic series $\sum \dfrac{1}{n}$ diverges.

In context:

1) The sum of the reciprocals of primes diverges as well.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

The sum of reciprocals of twin primes converges.

[Is the series $X =\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{11}+..$ convergent or divergent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497975/is-the-series-x-frac13-frac15-frac17-frac111-convergen)